# Как взять value по классу

Tags: javascript

Есть h1 с названием item`а.

```
<h1 class="hover_item_name" id="iteminfo1_item_name">Companion</h1>
```

Как взять название "Companion" из тега h1 по классу hover_item_name и записать его в переменную?

Comment: У тега h1 нет value.

Comment: тога как взять название Benevolent Companion и записать в переменную?

Comment: @MegaRoks innerHTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

innerHTML

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

```js
var val = document.getElementById("iteminfo1_item_name").innerHTML;
alert(`Значение: ${val}`)
```

```html
<h1 class="hover_item_name" id="iteminfo1_item_name">Benevolent Companion</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для получения текстового содержимого элемента, разумнее использовать свойство `textContent`, а не `innerHTML`.
Потому что элемент может содержать вложенные:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.hover_item_name'); 
console.log(`innerHTML: ${el.innerHTML}`); 
console.log(`textContent: ${el.textContent}`);
```

```html
<h1 class="hover_item_name" id="iteminfo1_item_name"><span>C</span>ompanion</h1>
```

Пример также демонстрирует выбор элемента именно по классу, а не по айди.